# is it possible to UNION and INNER JOIN for sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, union

im using the w3schools sql database to learn and i have come across a question.
is it possible to sort the results according to CustomerName after i have done a INNER JOIN?
this is the INNER JOIN statement

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Customers.ContactName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Just  .... try  ...

Comment: but your title seems not related  to the questions ..

Comment: Are you asking about UNION or ORDER BY?

Comment: basically i want to use the UNION fuction to ORDER BY Customer Name

Comment: SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Customers.ContactName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
UNION
SELECT * ORDER BY CustomerName; this is kinda of wat im thinking about but doesnt work so yea

Comment: Under no circumstances should you attempt anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` command in SQL is used to combine the results of your first query with the entire results of a second query that has the same columns. It is not used for ordering the first query. With your `INNER JOIN` you can sort the results just by adding `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Customers.ContactName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```